# Reading popen results in C++

Tags: c++, file, stream, popen, fstream

I am writing a C++ application and I need to read the result of a system command.

I am using `popen()` more or less as shown here:

```
    const int MAX_BUFFER = 2048;
    string cmd="ls -l";
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    FILE *stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (stream){
       while (!feof(stream))
       {
            if (fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL)
            {
               //here is all my code
            }
       }
       pclose(stream);
    }
```

I've been trying to re-write this in a different way. I saw some non-standard solutions like:

```
FILE *myfile;
std::fstream fileStream(myfile);
std::string mystring;
while(std::getline(myfile,mystring))
{
    // .... Here I do what I need
}
```

My compiler does not accept this though.

How can I read from `popen` in C++?

Comment: What is `here all my code`? Your first solution works perfectly if it's `data.append(buffer);`.

Comment: Could you publish the call stack from your crash?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, **complete** program that demonstrates your error. Start with you actual program, delete all of the lines that work, and show us just what is left. [Here](http://ideone.com/azOcT) is an examle of a working implementation of your first code fragment.  See http://sscce.org for more information about using this technique.

Comment: no. if the result is empty it crashes on the fgets

Comment: How do you know it crashes on fgets? Either you're in a debugger, or you have printfs inserted. Either get stack trace from the debugger or publish the actual code you're running, printf and all. The code you provide looks like it should run. Are you sure it crashes in fgets and not right after?

Comment: @Arkadiy Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x002e9e7a in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: I put some print and crashes there. however this is the result of gdb. ( not to good in using anyway )

Comment: Well, this location looks like it has nothing to do with fgets. I suspect that fgets puts no \0 at the end when it reads empty file. Try `buffer[0]=0` before reading.

Comment: tryed... still crash.
i do not understand what is readed if the result is empty...

Comment: @Rob. i think it was already quite short and concise. However i simplified it now as much as i could. i hope i made it more clear. cheers

Comment: Yes, @Stefano, it was quite short. But it was, and still is, incomplete. Please provide a minimal, **complete** program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Stefano, from your GDB output, the code is not dying in `fgets`, it is dying in `string::string(const string&)`. This is never called by your code fragment, so the problem is in the code which you *aren't* showing us.

Comment: Please type `bt 10` in gdb to get call stack. The GDB output you do provide points at std::string copy constructor that does not show up in your code sample. The crash must be in "here all I need" part.

Comment: guys... i am so so sorry... but u're right... te rror is elsewhere...i was in a blind mode being sure te error was there but it is not!... feel so sorry for have been insisting..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your example:

```
FILE *myfile;
std::fstream fileStream(myfile);
std::string mystring;
while(std::getline(myfile,mystring))
```

Does't work because although you're very close the standard library doesn't provide an `fstream` that can be constructed from a `FILE*`. [Boost iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) does however provide an `iostream` that can be constructed from a file descriptor and you can get one from a `FILE*` by calling `fileno`.

E.g.:

```
typedef boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>
        boost_stream; 

FILE *myfile; 
// make sure to popen and it succeeds
boost_stream stream(fileno(myfile));
stream.set_auto_close(false); // https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3517
std::string mystring;
while(std::getline(stream,mystring))
```

Don't forget to `pclose` later still.

Note: Newer versions of boost have deprecated the constructor which takes just a `fd`. Instead you need to pass one of `boost::iostreams::never_close_handle` or `boost::iostreams::close_handle` as a mandatory second argument to the constructor.

Comment: Some compilers provide non-standard extensions to the standard C++ library. A fstream constructor that takes a FILE* is a popular one. Which explains why it works on some compilers and not on others.

Comment: @Sjoerd - ah yes that would make sense. I wondered why it would be written like that. Still you can use a typedef to pick between an non-standard extension and a boost library at configure time in your build tool.

Comment: i tried with the standard constructor for fstream but was not accepted in my case. i'll try now in this way...

Comment: Didn't compile, I guess the sink should be source, since it's a read only example.

    boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source

Answer (score -4):

Here is something which i wrote long back, may help you. It might have some errors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

bool my_popen (const std::string& cmd,std::vector<std::string>& out ) {
    bool            ret_boolValue = true;
    FILE*           fp;
    const int       SIZEBUF = 1234;
    char            buf [SIZEBUF];
    out = std::vector<std::string> ();
    if ((fp = popen(cmd.c_str (), "r")) == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    std::string  cur_string = "";
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof (buf), fp)) {
        cur_string += buf;
    }
    out.push_back (cur_string.substr (0, cur_string.size () - 1));
    pclose(fp);
    return true;
}
int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
        std::vector<std::string> output;
        my_popen("ls -l > /dev/null ", output);
        for ( std::vector<std::string>::iterator itr = output.begin();
                                                 itr != output.end();
                                                 ++itr) {
                std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
        }

}
```