# reading the result of executed command with boost (C++ Libraries)

Tags: c++, boost, popen

I need help with this. Trying to execute a command from aplication developed in C++ and i want to read the result directly.

- OS: Debian 7 Wheezy
- boost_ver: 1.49 (from debian repository)
- compiler: g++

I have maked my program shortest possible to identify the problem.

Basically im trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807755/reading-popen-results-in-c).

But my problem lays else where, i think i dont know how to use boost library correctly (since this is the first time that im using other then std).

To cut long story short, here my code:

fd.cpp:

```
//STD libraries
#include <iostream>

//BOOST libraries
#include <stream.hpp>
#include <file_descriptor.hpp>

typedef boost::iostreams::stream  boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink>
        boost_stream;

int main() {

    FILE *file;

    file = popen("./dumm", "r");

    if (!file) {
        return 7;
    }

    boost_stream bs;

    pclose(file);

}
```

and my Makefile:

```
CPPC=g++
FLAGS=-Wall -fpermissive
INC=-I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/ -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/device/
SOURCES=fd.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXE=x

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): clean fd.o
    $(CPPC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

fd.o:
    $(CPPC) $(FLAGS) $(INC) -c $(SOURCES) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

I am able to compile fd.o, but not to make an executable. Are my includes correct? I think there could be problem.

I will not post the result of `make`, becouse its very long, basically it show some problem(s) with linking. But if you want i can edit&post it. Both codes should be executable.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

so the result of `make` is:

```
fd.o: In function `int boost::iostreams::detail::read_device_impl<boost::iostreams::input>::read<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor&, boost::iostreams::char_type_of<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor>::type*, int)':
fd.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams6detail16read_device_implINS0_5inputEE4readINS0_15file_descriptorEEEiRT_PNS0_12char_type_ofIS7_E4typeEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams6detail16read_device_implINS0_5inputEE4readINS0_15file_descriptorEEEiRT_PNS0_12char_type_ofIS7_E4typeEi]+0x1b): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::read(char*, int)'
fd.o: In function `int boost::iostreams::detail::write_device_impl<boost::iostreams::output>::write<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor&, boost::iostreams::char_type_of<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor>::type const*, int)':
fd.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams6detail17write_device_implINS0_6outputEE5writeINS0_15file_descriptorEEEiRT_PKNS0_12char_type_ofIS7_E4typeEi[_ZN5boost9iostreams6detail17write_device_implINS0_6outputEE5writeINS0_15file_descriptorEEEiRT_PKNS0_12char_type_ofIS7_E4typeEi]+0x1b): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::write(char const*, int)'
fd.o: In function `void boost::iostreams::detail::close_impl<boost::iostreams::closable_tag>::close<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor&, std::_Ios_Openmode)':
fd.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams6detail10close_implINS0_12closable_tagEE5closeINS0_15file_descriptorEEEvRT_St13_Ios_Openmode[_ZN5boost9iostreams6detail10close_implINS0_12closable_tagEE5closeINS0_15file_descriptorEEEvRT_St13_Ios_Openmode]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::close()'
fd.o: In function `std::fpos<__mbstate_t> boost::iostreams::detail::seek_device_impl<boost::iostreams::any_tag>::seek<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor>(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor&, long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)':
fd.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9iostreams6detail16seek_device_implINS0_7any_tagEE4seekINS0_15file_descriptorEEESt4fposI11__mbstate_tERT_xSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode[_ZN5boost9iostreams6detail16seek_device_implINS0_7any_tagEE4seekINS0_15file_descriptorEEESt4fposI11__mbstate_tERT_xSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode]+0x35): undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::seek(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [x] Error 1
```

**EDIT 2:**

updated Makefile:

```
    CPPC=g++
    FLAGS=-Wall -fpermissive
    INC=-I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/ -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/device/ -L/usr/lib/
    SOURCES=fd.cpp
    OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
    EXE=x

    all: $(EXE)

    $(EXE): clean fd.o
        $(CPPC) $(INC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

    fd.o:
        $(CPPC) $(FLAGS) $(INC) -c $(SOURCES) -o $@

    clean:
        rm -f $(EXE)
```

And its still not working. I didnt make diff between error message of old and new Makefile, but looks pretty the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say w/o seeing actual error but one of the reasons may be that parts of boost::iostream require linking to compiled boost iostream library and regex. If that's not the case, please provide just the linker errors here, it'll let us help you better.

**EDIT**
I'm not really familiar with how G++ would express missing lib, but it loooks to me that this is the problem.

Looks like boost auto linking feature is not working here (otherwise you'd get explicit missing lib error with lib file name), so you need to verify that you:

1. have built boost libs
2. have included boost iostream lib in your makefile

That should help, or at least fix some of the errors.

Comment: I have never done that before. I founded compiler boost libraries (.so files) in /usr/lib so I add "-L/usr/lib/" to linker line in Makefile but it didnt help. But i am not sure if thats what are you thinking about.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I meant. Could you show updated makefile as well as comlete error message then?

Comment: I have installed boost through debian package manager (apt-get). It seems that all the compiled libraries are in /usr/lib/. I think i dont have sources so i cannot recompile and rebuild them. I have included /usr/lib/ as a library include compilator and linker. And i did it also with /usr/lib/libboost-* and it sill did not helped (still the same error message)

Comment: Your updated makefile still doesn't tell linker to include any .so or .a boost files.

Comment: i tried do it like: -L/usr/lib/libboost-*. It should ichlude all .a and .so files. Should i write it explicitly? Like -L/usr/lib/libboost-iostreams.so -L/usr/lib/libboost-iostreams-mt.a ... and so on? Well i already tried it with -L/usr/lib/libboost-iostreams.so and it did not worked (same error message)

Comment: @Addman: You're confusing the `-L` option and the `-l` option. `-L` adds a directory to your library path. It does not specify a library to link. `/usr/lib/` should be in your library path by default. I think all you need is `-lboost-iostreams` on your link command.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Iostreams is not a header-only library. You need to link to it by adding something like this to your link command: `-lboost-iostreams`.