# C++ equivalent of fgets for reading from popen

Tags: c++

I need to process some data from standard output. Here is the code I am using:

```
FILE* in;
in = popen("ls -a", "r");
char line[256]
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL) {
    // do something with line
}
```

Which works fine but there is a problem if the line is longer than 256 bytes. So now I tried the following but it is not a good solution:

```
FILE* in;
in = popen("ls -a", "r");
char line[100000000] // Wow
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL) {
    // do something with line
}
```

How do I use c++ to avoid having to specify the line size? I.e. be able to handle a line of any length?

**Edit, getline doesn't work! :=[[**

```
FILE *in;
std::string line;
while(std::getline(in, line))
{
   // Says no matching function =((((
}
```

Comment: Look up `std::getline`.

Comment: @nwp: You mean, a function that won't work here?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition yes getline doesn't work :((

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `std::getline()` before claiming "it doesn't work"? It works just fine, you just have to use it correctly (using a C++ input stream instead of a C `FILE *`).

Comment: @DevSolar: And how do you intend to get `popen` to work with a C++ input stream?

Comment: Removed my original answer, I missed the `popen()`. So, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807755/reading-popen-results-in-c.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: [PStreams](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/), [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/), ... -- but just tossing a `FILE *` into `std::getline()` shows the OP would probably be overtaxed with such a suggestion.

Comment: @DevSolar: Those are not `popen`. They are valid alternatives, but they are not `popen`. So, you did not answer my question. Try again? :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: No need to get defensive about it. `popen()` forks, and invokes the shell with the given command. Either PStreams and Boost.Process fork, and invoke the shell -- only in a C++ way, which was the **intention** of the OP's question: How to do the `popen()` / `fgets()` thing *the C++ way*. And if you insist on calling `popen()`, check the first comment under my answer regarding Boost.Iostreams (which I added as a comment because I don't "borrow" from other people's answers).

Comment: @DevSolar: I'm not "getting defensive about it"; I am stating a fact. _You're_ getting defensive about it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C++ solution would use `std::string` instead of `char[]`, `std::getline` instead of `fgets()`, and input streams instead of `FILE *`.

The one problem is the POSIX function `popen()` -- for which various C++ alternatives exist, among others...

[PStreams](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/)

```
#include "pstream.h"
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    redi::ipstream is("ls -a");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) (as of 1.64 "officially" [part of Boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/process.html))

```
#include "boost/process.hpp"
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{ 
    boost::process::context ctx; 
    ctx.stdout_behavior = boost::process::capture_stream();

    std::string exe( "ls" );
    std::vector< std::string > args;
    args.push_back( "-a" );

    boost::process::child c = boost::process::launch( exe, args, ctx); 

    boost::process::pistream &is = c.get_stdout(); 

    std::string line; 
    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use Boost.Iostreams to turn the `FILE *` you got from `popen()` into a C++ istream, as per [this answer to the question linked by @Rene above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7807918/60281).

Comment: FWIW, I use Boost.Process. Although I do find that it murders compile times under some circumstances (never did find out why).

Comment: Maybe using std::system could help.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: The difference between `system()` (which is a C function actually) and `popen()` is that `popen()` allows you to capture the output of the command executed... while `system()` doesn't. So I don't see what `system()` would achieve in the context of the question.

Comment: @DevSolar He could redirect to a file, and then read that file as a C++ stream, something like this:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: @ErikAlapää: Yes, and he could do that in C as well, but why should he with all the nice alternatives already presented here, and even his initial C-only solution superior to `system()`?

Comment: @ErikAlapää: Besides, going through a temporary external file opens up a whole new can of (security-related) worms...

Comment: Here is a solution I found on the net a while ago, simple C++ RAII wrapper of popen, basically: https://github.com/alapaa/timestamping/blob/send_queue/src/util.cpp#L34

Comment: error: ‘context’ is not a member of ‘boost::process’

Comment: @SuB: Cannot reproduce, but I got *different* errors when I tried the above code. Strange, I *know* I tested it when I posted. Edited to work with Boost 1.58 (which is what I have available here).

Comment: @SuB: Apparently Boost.Process finally made it into Boost proper (as of 1.64).

Comment: @SuB: All I have available here ATM is Boost 1.58 and the version of Boost.Process from the author's homepage (which works). If you have problems with the version shipping with Boost 1.64, I suggest either opening your own question here on Stackoverflow, or (if you are positive that you haven't made any mistake) contacting the author with a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (preferably, giving some [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which would be updated) or [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

<sup>(however, standard C++ don't know about `popen`....)</sup>

BTW, on POSIX, with both C and C++ you might use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (dealing with some `malloc`-ed `char*`buffer read from some `FILE*` handle).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The C++ standard library functions can't hook into arbitrary `FILE*`s (at least, not without hacks).

The typical approach here is to read in chunks of, say, 512 bytes. Then, *iff* you need the entire result in a single buffer, append into a `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` inside that loop. Yes, it'll result in a bit of data copying, but your computer can handle it. And you'd always have had to do this anyway.

Comment: Just because the *standard* library cannot do something does not justify the claim "you can't". The *standard* C library cannot do `popen()` either.

Comment: @DevSolar: Go ahead and name a GNU, POSIX or C function that automatically allocates sufficient space for the data read from `popen`. Your answer (suggesting alternatives to `popen`) is good, but I have accurately answered the actual question posed.